# Pause/Suspend guest in KVM without virsh and libvirtd

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I have installed KVM without libvirt/virsh and virtualmanager.

Packages which installed are kvm qemu-kvm bridge-utils libguestfs-tools

How can I pause/suspend VM in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a monitor command:

> When QEMU is running, it provides a monitor console for interacting
>   with QEMU. Through various commands, the monitor allows you to inspect
>   the running guest OS, change removable media and USB devices, take
>   screenshots and audio grabs, and control various aspects of the
>   virtual machine.
>
> The monitor is accessed from within QEMU by holding down the Ctrl and
>   Alt keys (or whatever the "mouse grab" keystrokes are), and pressing
>   Shift-2. Once in the monitor, Shift-1 switches back to the guest OS.
>   Typing help or ? in the monitor brings up a list of all commands.
>   Alternatively the monitor can be redirected to using the -monitor
>    command line option. Using -monitor stdio will send the monitor
>   to the standard output, this is most useful when using qemu on the
>   command line.

Some relevant commands:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor#Virtual_machine

Comment: Thank you! In addition, for flexible management of guest I used this article: https://nico.schottelius.org/blog/control-and-shutdown-qemu-kvm-vm-via-unix-socket/ hope it will help for somebody else.

Comment: You could access with `-monitor stdio` from the qemu command.